# Lost in a field of Degrees and certifications

Tags: professional-education, career

I have another semester or so before I graduate with my As in Information security. This is going to be a two part question.  Other than the degree I will also have a few different certifications. Also adding a small 140 hour internship with my last semester.

CompTIA A+
CompTIA Security+
CompTIA Network+

With the degree and the certs what I will have other than help desk what am I looking at for employment.

Part two of this question is more schooling. I really want to move forward with a BS in a field of information security, assurance, or cybersecurity. I am however having a hard time finding a bachelor’s degree in one of those fields. I live in Florida and would like to attend an online school for this. I really do not want to take just a general IT degree. So any knowledge or help would be great.

Comment: What is Part 1 of your question? I think it needs re-wording.

Comment: Do you want a BS specifically? I mostly see BA and BTech as options. I'm not sure that a BS exists for InfoSec (because it's not science)

Comment: We have a bachelors in infosec at my uni/college, but with the exemption of some very basic introductory modules, it's pretty much regular IT. Personally, I tell anyone who asks what I study that: I study IT and will take masters in infosec, even though the name of my bachelor is information security.

Comment: Your degrees are stuffed with absolutely nothing at all. Out in the fields, you have show what you can. E.g. can you stop a Chinese icebreaker?

Comment: Certifications aren't worth much, and information security knowledge with no software (or hardware) engineering background is of limited use. If this is the field you want to get in, you're probably going to want to pursue a computer science or computer engineering degree of some sort (or gain equivalent knowledge through experience).

Comment: I have to disagree with degrees mean nothing. If you are getting hired through a HR department and your resume does not say bachelors or masters on it they don't even look. I am currently in school with plenty of people with 10+ years in the field and they cant get a job because of no degree.

Comment: As far as the first question goes. I was wondering what type of job i can expect once i graduate with only the AS degree. I plan to keep going to school but i would like to start getting exp under my belt. I also am having a hard time finding a degree other than a basic IT degree for my bachelors. So i came here looking for a little help.

Comment: I have to say i get a lot of mixed signals. I talk to this person and they say you cant do it without the certs and degree. I talk to others and they say the certs are useless.

Comment: This site isn't a forum board for Florida residents I'm afraid... There are probably hundreds of degrees in information security on this planet, and you're using abbreviations specific to one educational system, and asking for recommendations in that one educational system and even in a specific US state. Could you make the second part of your question more general and tangible to people outside Florida so that it may serve future readers too?

Comment: i Never said the college had to be in Florida. I really just am looking for degrees in or closer to the field I want to be in. They can be any type of bachelors really. I am just asking for help here.

Answer (score 1):

I am in a similar Situation, about to get my first cert, and doing an internship right now.

If you'd like to take online classes related to Cyber Security I can recommend Dakota State University. I am a student there and while the campus/school are relatively small the classes are awesome.

The School is known for it's great program and does a great job at balancing hands on experience with lectures (at least in my opinion).

Here is some info on my Major (It's called Cyber Operations, but that's just a fancy word for Computer Security mixed with Computer Science).

[DSU Cyber Operations](http://dsu.edu/academics/degrees-and-programs/cyber-operations-bs)

One main PRO about DSU is that it's part of the NSA funded program called Cyber Core, which is a crazy good scholarship for students just like yourself. Another PRO is that it's a great place to network. Most Professors and Instructors are ether very experienced in their field and one of my instructors even works for the NSA (Great guy, don't even care if he reads my FB messages). This is my second internship and I have to say I would never have thought that I could get this far solely on the connections I made through Teachers and mentors here.

If you want some more info feel free to contact me, I'd be glad to tell you more about it!

Comment: Do they offer the degree online

Comment: Yes I believe so, click that link and see on the right hand side

Comment: I was just looking into it and the 450 a credit hour it a little much for me but thanks for your input